# Force close onclick intent

Tags: android

I have tried searching and to troubleshoot for hours, but I still could not figure out why will my app force close.

When I click on the text, it switches and displays figure603.xml perfectly, but then force close appears.

Any one could advice me what went wrong?

figure603.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/figure"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

figure603.java

```
package com.rufflez.swipeytabs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class figure603 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.figure603);
    }

}
```

Fragment_6.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class Fragment_6 extends SherlockFragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_6, container, false); // inflate the layout
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1); // initialize textview using inflated view object 

        tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), figure603.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        }); 
        return v;
}

}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.rufflez.swipeytabs"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" /><application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity 
        android:name="com.rufflez.swipeytabs.MainActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:name=".figure603" ></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat

```
12-04 09:00:45.331: D/dalvikvm(2426): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 48K, 4% free 2999K/3112K, paused 125ms, total 126ms
12-04 09:00:45.351: I/dalvikvm-heap(2426): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.062MB for 1127536-byte allocation
12-04 09:00:45.401: D/dalvikvm(2426): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 4100K/4216K, paused 50ms, total 50ms
12-04 09:00:45.871: V/21st Polling:(2426): clicked
12-04 09:00:46.341: D/(2426): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8973b10, tid 2426
12-04 09:00:46.401: W/EGL_emulation(2426): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-04 09:00:46.421: D/OpenGLRenderer(2426): Enabling debug mode 0
12-04 09:00:50.921: V/21st Polling:(2426): clicked
12-04 09:00:53.121: D/dalvikvm(2426): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 101K, 4% free 4492K/4656K, paused 48ms, total 60ms
12-04 09:00:53.191: I/dalvikvm-heap(2426): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.610MB for 1221624-byte allocation
12-04 09:00:53.301: D/dalvikvm(2426): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 4% free 5674K/5852K, paused 115ms, total 115ms
12-04 09:00:53.821: W/EGL_emulation(2426): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-04 09:00:54.661: D/AndroidRuntime(2426): Shutting down VM
12-04 09:00:54.661: W/dalvikvm(2426): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a77b90)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426): Process: com.rufflez.swipeytabs, PID: 2426
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1617)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:481)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:126)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1152)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1223)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3156)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3215)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 09:00:56.741: I/Process(2426): Sending signal. PID: 2426 SIG: 9
```

TabsAdapter.java

```
package com.rufflez.swipeytabs;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener , ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
private final Context mContext;
private final ActionBar mActionBar;
private final ViewPager mViewPager;
private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
private final String TAG = "21st Polling:";

static final class TabInfo{
    private final Class<?> clss;
    private final Bundle args;

    TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args){
        clss = _class;
        args = _args;
    }
}

public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity fa, ViewPager pager) {
    super(fa.getSupportFragmentManager());
    mContext = fa;
    mActionBar = fa.getSupportActionBar();
    mViewPager = pager;
    mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args){
    TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
    tab.setTag(info);
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    mTabs.add(info);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {


}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    Log.v(TAG, "clicked");
    Object tag = tab.getTag();
    for (int i = 0; i<mTabs.size(); i++){
        if (mTabs.get(i) == tag){
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "You've deselected a tab", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
    return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mTabs.size();
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
package com.rufflez.swipeytabs;


import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);

    final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setTitle("TASK 05-55-08-200-803");

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("A. General"), Fragment_1.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("B. References"), Fragment_2.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("C. Tools/Equipment"), Fragment_3.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("D. Location Zones"), Fragment_4.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("E. Prepare for Procedure"), Fragment_5.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("F. Procedure"), Fragment_6.class, null);


}
}
```

Comment: How are you using the Fragment? Are you keeping any direct reference to it and re-use that later?

Comment: 12-04 09:00:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2426):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:126) <- what are you doing on this line?

Comment: @clavio : unless Catherine is a developer from actionBarSherlock, this is not a line they wrote...

Comment: @gunar i'm not sure if i am answering your question but i am using fragments to swipe left and right so i can go from Fragment_1 to Fragment_2 up to 6.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code from your `PagerAdapter` implementation?

Comment: @gunar i have posted the TabsAdapter.java is this the correct one?

Comment: i have also posted MainActivity.java, appreciate your help!

Comment: I would try to separate the PagerAdapter from TabListener since you have a single class that is directly referenced both from ViewPager and Tab implementation. I am not sure it will work, but it's a starting point

Comment: Make the activity to be a TabListener

Comment: @gunar thanks for your help! the fragments are working, i set a clickable text on Fragment_6, and it is suppose to switch to figure603.xml when i click on the text. it switches to figure603.xml with the image, however it force close after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, add `android:exported="true"` in the activity component.

```
<activity
    android:name=".youractivities"
    android:exported="true" />
```

Comment: Agree with this solution, since Android 12, you need to add android:exported="true" on each activity inside your androidmanifest

Comment: @ahmfarisi : You can see the official documentation about Android 12 behavior changes. [**Apps targeting Android 12**] (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12)